# Draw a map of a specific country with cartopy?

Tags: python, geo, cartopy

I have tried [this example](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/lines_and_polygons/hurricane_katrina.html) from the Cartopy gallery, which works fine. But how do I focus on another country, i.e. show only Germany?

[image: example of US map]

I've tried some coordinates on the extend() method, but I didn't manage to get to look it like the US map. Or do I have to modify the shape file?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using the Global Administrative Areas dataset at http://www.gadm.org/country, just download the Germany dataset and use cartopy's shapereader (in the same way as is done in the linked example).

A short-self contained example:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Downloaded from http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/shp/DEU_adm.zip
fname = '/downloads/DEU/DEU_adm1.shp'

adm1_shapes = list(shpreader.Reader(fname).geometries())

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.title('Deutschland')
ax.coastlines(resolution='10m')

ax.add_geometries(adm1_shapes, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                  edgecolor='black', facecolor='gray', alpha=0.5)

ax.set_extent([4, 16, 47, 56], ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.show()
```

[image: Output from code]

HTH

Comment: An answer from the creator of Cartopy himself -- gotta love Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is there a way to label country names in cartopy?

Comment: So what if I want to merge Germany and the Netherlands. Can I somehow merge the shape files to show two countries and mask the rest out?

Answer (score 17):

Let me just ad an example using the data from [naturalearthdata](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/). So it is possible to extend this to any country.

```py
from cartopy.io import shapereader
import numpy as np
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# get natural earth data (http://www.naturalearthdata.com/)

# get country borders
resolution = '10m'
category = 'cultural'
name = 'admin_0_countries'

shpfilename = shapereader.natural_earth(resolution, category, name)

# read the shapefile using geopandas
df = geopandas.read_file(shpfilename)

# read the german borders
poly = df.loc[df['ADMIN'] == 'Germany']['geometry'].values[0]

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_geometries(poly, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), facecolor='none', 
                  edgecolor='0.5')

ax.set_extent([5, 16, 46.5, 56], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

This yields the following figure:

[image: Figure Germany]

Comment: As of cartopy 0.18 I had to change `ax.add_geometries(poly, ...)` to `ax.add_geometries([poly] ...)`