# Draw state lines of specific countries with cartopy

Tags: python, cartopy

When drawing cartopy maps, I add state lines with

```
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature(
    'cultural', 'admin_1_states_provinces_lines', resolution,
    edgecolor='gray', facecolor='none'))
```

where `resolution` is `'110m'`, `'50m'` or `'10m'`. The 110m dataset only contains US states, but the others contain far more.

I would like to draw state lines only for selected countries (regardless of the resolution selected), like e.g. only US, Canada and Australia.

I found a similar question in [Draw a map of a specific country with cartopy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428512/draw-a-map-of-a-specific-country-with-cartopy) and downloaded the US shape file from [gadm.org](http://www.gadm.org/country). I added the states using

```
us_shapes = list(shpreader.Reader('shapefiles/gadm36_USA_1.shp').geometries())
ax.add_geometries(us_shapes, ccrs.PlateCarree(), edgecolor='gray',
                  facecolor='none')
```

But this creates two problem for me:

- The shapes also contain the country (US in this case) border itself, which I had previously drawn in black. I can of course draw the country borders after the state borders, but this is somewhat superfluous since a lot of coast line is drawn twice. Is there a way to only get the state lines within the country (so without country border)?
- The shape file seems to contain a very fine resolution (maybe 10m?). When I draw the world map with 110m resolution, I would prefer to only get the state lines in 110m. Otherwise the time to draw the map is significantly larger and the country/state shapes are not perfectly on top. Does the shape file also contain the lower resolutions?

The following image shows the problem:
[image: Cartopy World Map with added US states]

Comment: To avoid `coastlines being drawn twice` in your case, involves a lot more work on complex coding. I will wait and see the answers.

Comment: @swatchai OK, I guess I can live with the coastlines being drawn twice, but I definitely need them in the correct resolutions to match the rest.