# Get information about a specific country from Cartopy shapereader records

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, generator, cartopy

I'm plotting world map-data at a country level, using the geometries provided in the Cartopy shapereader natural earth records:

```
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import pandas as pd

my_data = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv", index_col = 0)

shpfilename = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='50m',
                                      category='cultural',
                                      name='admin_0_countries')
reader = shpreader.Reader(shpfilename)
countries = reader.records()

for country in countries:

   sovgt = country.attribute["SOVEREIGNT"]

   plot_val = my_data.loc[sovgt]

   ax.add_geometries([country.geometry],
                     ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                     facecolor = cmap(plot_val))
```

My question is: is there a neater way to extract data about a specific country from `countries` given that it is a generator. It would be highly preferable if I could do something like

```
for country in my_data.index.to_list():
   
   geometry = countries[country].geometry

   ax.add_geometries(geometry,
                     ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                     facecolor = cmap(plot_val))
```

The reason for this is that my index of countries in `my_data` does not align with the names of countries in `countries`. I have a tiered list of `try:, except KeyError:` with dicts of names to handle all the dependant states etc that aren't listed seperately in my dataset.

This is probably a more general question about generator objects. Apologies if it also a stupid question.

Comment: Check this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925988/merge-countries-using-cartopy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any insight for generators, but I answered a related question about colouring a nation on a map from a list of nation names and values https://stackoverflow.com/a/61525984/13208790

The key step is reading the natural earth data into geopandas, so you have a dataframe rather than a generator to work with. Not very elegant but should work:

```
import geopandas
from cartopy.io import shapereader
shpfilename = shapereader.natural_earth('50m', 'cultural', 'admin_0_countries')
df = geopandas.read_file(shpfilename)
df.head()
```